# Issue uploading jar-files to Azure Web App

Tags: eclipse, azure, jar

I've created a Web App with PostgreSQL and Tomcat 8.5 in Azure, and running java 8.
I'm using Eclipse, and have a local version of Tomcat. If I'm running the project locally, I'm able to contact the PostgreSQL. But when I push the project to Azure, I'm getting an error what it can't find the postgre driver.

Anyone have a step by step guide for uploading .jar-files to Azure web apps? I've tried with other projects that don't need postgres, but other .jar-files, and same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try publish it using maven. Here are useful links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-java

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-java

If the database is also on Azure, you'll need to enable trafic from azure to it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-firewall-rules